# How to make a request parameter optional in Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

I know `fieldWithPath()` has `optional()` but didn't find how to make `parameterWithName()` optional.

Answer (score 3):

In Spring REST Docs 1.1 you can [mark request and path parameters as optional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/169). If you want that information to also appear in the generated table you can use a custom snippet that adds the optional column (once [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/226) has been fixed).

In Spring REST Docs 1.0 you can't mark a request parameter as optional via a first-class API. I would recommend using a combination of a custom attribute on the parameter descriptor and, if necessary, setting the ignored flag on the descriptor to allow the test to pass in the parameter's absence.

Comment: Just throwing in my 2 cents for feed back.   I VERY much disagree that having an optional column is not warranted.   That is a critical detail of each field and is something in pretty much all documentation.    I know about the adding attributes option, but that requires a lot of extra code and often does not seem to work.   The attributes frequently do not show up in the generated snippets.

Comment: @BrianC The functionality you're looking for is coming in 1.1. I've updated my answer accordingly. If you are having trouble with adding attributes not working, please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/new) with a testcase that illustrates the problem.